# Dataframe groupby to get stints

Tags: python, pandas

I have a new code I'm trying to write where a dataframe gets filtered/edited to obtain "stints" for each individual. Using the dataframe below as an example, I'm basically trying to get each persons start/end dates for a given location. Usually I can get started on my own but I'm stumped as to how to approach this so if anyone has ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

|  | Person | Location | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | A | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | Tom | A | 1/2/2021 |
| 2 | Tom | A | 1/3/2021 |
| 3 | Tom | B | 1/4/2021 |
| 4 | Tom | B | 1/5/2021 |
| 5 | Tom | B | 1/6/2021 |
| 6 | Tom | A | 1/7/2021 |
| 7 | Tom | A | 1/8/2021 |
| 8 | Tom | A | 1/9/2021 |
| 9 | Tom | C | 1/10/2021 |
| 10 | Tom | C | 1/11/2021 |
| 11 | Tom | A | 1/12/2021 |
| 12 | Tom | A | 1/13/2021 |
| 13 | Tom | B | 1/14/2021 |
| 14 | Tom | B | 1/15/2021 |
| 15 | Mark | A | 1/1/2021 |
| 16 | Mark | A | 1/2/2021 |
| 17 | Mark | B | 1/3/2021 |
| 18 | Mark | B | 1/4/2021 |
| 19 | Mark | A | 1/5/2021 |
| 20 | Mark | A | 1/6/2021 |
| 21 | Mark | C | 1/7/2021 |
| 22 | Mark | C | 1/8/2021 |
| 23 | Mark | C | 1/9/2021 |
| 24 | Mark | C | 1/10/2021 |
| 25 | Mark | A | 1/11/2021 |
| 26 | Mark | A | 1/12/2021 |
| 27 | Mark | B | 1/13/2021 |
| 28 | Mark | B | 1/14/2021 |
| 29 | Mark | B | 1/15/2021 |

Expected outcome:

|  | Person | Location | StintNum | Start_Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | A | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1/3/2021 |
| 1 | Tom | B | 2 | 1/4/2021 | 1/6/2021 |
| 2 | Tom | A | 3 | 1/7/2021 | 1/9/2021 |
| 3 | Tom | C | 4 | 1/10/2021 | 1/11/2021 |
| 4 | Tom | A | 5 | 1/12/2021 | 1/13/2021 |
| 5 | Tom | B | 6 | 1/14/2021 | 1/15/2021 |
| 6 | Mark | A | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1/2/2021 |
| 7 | Mark | B | 2 | 1/3/2021 | 1/4/2021 |
| 8 | Mark | A | 3 | 1/5/2021 | 1/6/2021 |
| 9 | Mark | C | 4 | 1/7/2021 | 1/10/2021 |
| 10 | Mark | A | 5 | 1/11/2021 | 1/12/2021 |
| 11 | Mark | B | 6 | 1/13/2021 | 1/15/2021 |

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe? Also, what does "stints" mean?

Comment: A stint is a period of time at a certain location. Can you not see the table I posted in the question?

Comment: I can see the table, but is that what you have originally? Or is it what you want to end up with? Or what?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, that is the original. I can also post the expected outcome.

Comment: Please do, thank you :)

Comment: Added, hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, a clean way is to use `groupby`+`agg`, this enables to set custom aggregators easily and is faster than `apply`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

group = df['Location'].ne(df['Location'].shift()).cumsum()

df2 = (
 df.groupby(['Person', group], as_index=False)
   .agg(Location=('Location', 'first'),
        # line below is a dummy function to set a column placeholder
        # uncomment it you want the columns in order
        #StintNum=('Location', lambda x: float('NaN')),
        Start_Date=('Date', 'min'), 
        End_Date=('Date', 'max'),
       )
)

df2['StintNum'] = df2.groupby('Person').cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
   Person Location  StintNum Start_Date   End_Date
0    Mark        A         1 2021-01-01 2021-01-02
1    Mark        B         2 2021-01-03 2021-01-04
2    Mark        A         3 2021-01-05 2021-01-06
3    Mark        C         4 2021-01-07 2021-01-10
4    Mark        A         5 2021-01-11 2021-01-12
5    Mark        B         6 2021-01-13 2021-01-15
6     Tom        A         1 2021-01-01 2021-01-03
7     Tom        B         2 2021-01-04 2021-01-06
8     Tom        A         3 2021-01-07 2021-01-09
9     Tom        C         4 2021-01-10 2021-01-11
10    Tom        A         5 2021-01-12 2021-01-13
11    Tom        B         6 2021-01-14 2021-01-15
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
new_df = df.groupby([df['Person'], df['Location'].ne(df['Location'].shift(1)).cumsum()], sort=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x['Date'].min(), x['Date'].max()], index=['Start_Date','End_Date'])).reset_index()
new_df['StintNum'] = new_df.groupby('Person').cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   Person  Location Start_Date   End_Date  StintNum
0     Tom         1 2021-01-01 2021-01-03         1
1     Tom         2 2021-01-04 2021-01-06         2
2     Tom         3 2021-01-07 2021-01-09         3
3     Tom         4 2021-01-10 2021-01-11         4
4     Tom         5 2021-01-12 2021-01-13         5
5     Tom         6 2021-01-14 2021-01-15         6
6    Mark         7 2021-01-01 2021-01-02         1
7    Mark         8 2021-01-03 2021-01-04         2
8    Mark         9 2021-01-05 2021-01-06         3
9    Mark        10 2021-01-07 2021-01-10         4
10   Mark        11 2021-01-11 2021-01-12         5
11   Mark        12 2021-01-13 2021-01-15         6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.groupby(["Person","Location"],as_index=False).agg(StintNum=("col1","first"),Start_Date=("Date",min),End_Date=("Date",max))
    return dd1

col1=df1.groupby("Person",group_keys=False).apply(lambda dd:dd.Location.ne(dd.Location.shift()).cumsum())

df1.assign(col1=col1).groupby(["Person","col1"],sort=False).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
  Person Location  StintNum Start_Date   End_Date
0     Tom        A         1   1/1/2021   1/3/2021
1     Tom        B         2   1/4/2021   1/6/2021
2     Tom        A         3   1/7/2021   1/9/2021
3     Tom        C         4  1/10/2021  1/11/2021
4     Tom        A         5  1/12/2021  1/13/2021
5     Tom        B         6  1/14/2021  1/15/2021
6    Mark        A         1   1/1/2021   1/2/2021
7    Mark        B         2   1/3/2021   1/4/2021
8    Mark        A         3   1/5/2021   1/6/2021
9    Mark        C         4  1/10/2021   1/9/2021
10   Mark        A         5  1/11/2021  1/12/2021
11   Mark        B         6  1/13/2021  1/15/2021
```